# is it possible to use MARKDOWN with the web2py built-in wiki?

Tags: python, web2py, wiki

Is it possible to use `MARKDOWN` instead of `MARKMIN` or `HTML` for the web2py's built in `auth.wiki()`? It doesn't seem like it's one of the standard render options, but I'm not sure. Is it as simple as:

```
from gluon.contrib.markdown import WIKI as MARKDOWN
wiki = auth.wiki(render=MARKDOWN)
```

or is there something more complicated that needs to be done? I like the `MARKMIN` syntax, but it seems like `MARKDOWN` is more full-featured.